# Null values for INT columns in hive while loading data from CSV file

Tags: csv, hive

When I load data from csv file into hive table, all int headers except string header show null.

I have pokemon.csv file with column headers as below

```
#   Name    Type 1  Type 2  Total   HP  Attack  Defense Sp. Atk Sp. Def Speed
1   Bulbasaur   Grass   Poison  318 45  49  49  65  65  45
2   Ivysaur Grass   Poison  405 60  62  63  80  80  60
3   Venusaur    Grass   Poison  525 80  82  83  100 100 80
```

I have ceated table as below

```
CREATE TABLE pokemon (
Number Int,
Name String,
Type1 String,
Type2 String,
Total Int,
HP Int,
Attack Int,
Defense Int,
Sp_Atk Int,
Sp_Def Int,
Speed Int
) 
row format delimited 
fields terminated BY ',' 
lines terminated BY '\n' 
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

I get result as below

```
hive> select * from pokemon limit 2;         
OK
NULL    Name    Type 1  Type 2  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   Bulbasaur   Grass   Poison  318 45  49  49  65  65  45
Time taken: 0.163 seconds
```

Not sure why am I getting NULL headers only for INT columns. Please can any one help?

Comment: In your csv example fields are not `terminated by ','`

Comment: But if they are terminated by ',' then all fields should show NULL but here only Int columns are NULL.

Comment: Are there any TABs (\t) in it? or spaces only? Check this please

Comment: No. i had another csv data file in that too i was getting INT columns NULL. Issue seems to be only with INT columns